# Actualizar solo el campo que se ha enviando usando PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

Estoy haciendo un blog, y cuando edito dicho blog por ejemplo el título, las demás variables se declaran como `undefinex`, ¿qué se puede hacer en este caso?

```
$body  = $_POST['body-post'];
    $title  = $_POST['title-post'];
    $img = $_POST['avatar-post'];
    $idautor = $_POST['idautor'];
    $catid = $_POST['categoria-post'];
    if ($title == "" || $catid == "" || $body == "" || $idautor == "" || $img == "" ) {
        echo "Campos vacios";
    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_post(cat, title, body, image, id_autor, tags) 
            VALUES ('$catid', '$title' ,'$body','$img','$idautor', '')";

            $inserted_rows = mysql_query($query);
            if ($inserted_rows) {
                echo "Bien datos Insertados";
                header("Location: ../../index.php");
            }
    }
```

Comment: Prueba con un echo en $title, $img... para ver si estas recibiendo Parametros

Answer (score 1):

también podes verificar que estas recibiendo en $_POST, agrega esto en tu script php

print_r($_POST);
die;

Si no vienen las variables que necesitas asegurate que en el origen de la petición no haya error

Answer (score 0):

si estas pasando los datos por ajax verifica que se estén capturando bien los datos del formulario y que se estén pasando al script de php. Si lo estas haciendo directamente desde del submit verifica que estén bien los nombre del campo del formulario  con lo de la  variable global $_POST.

Nota: El código que colocas es para realizar el Insert no Update.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando AJAX te recomiendo lo siguiente

```
$body  = $_REQUEST['body-post'];
    $title  = $_REQUEST['title-post'];
    $img = $_REQUEST['avatar-post'];
    $idautor = $_REQUEST['idautor'];
    $catid = $_REQUEST['categoria-post'];
```

$_REQUEST en vez de $_POST además has un echo de las variables a ver que traen.
¿Podrías postear tu AJAX?